# Excel VBA - finding max for winter months

Tags: excel, vba

I'm writing a macro public function for finding max of the last `N` non empty cells for winter months (November, December, January, February).

Here's what I got:

```
Public Function SuperMax_Winter(rng2 As Range, rng As Range, N As Long) As Double
Dim RngCnt, RngCnt2 As Long, i As Long, Zum As Double, j As Long
Dim ary() As Double
ReDim ary(0)

j = 0
RngCnt = rng.Count
RngCnt2 = rng2.Count

If RngCnt <> RngCnt2 Then SuperMax_Winter = "#ERROR!"

For i = RngCnt To 1 Step -1
    If rng(i).Value <> "" Then
        If rng2(i).Month = 11 Or rng2(i).Month = 12 Or rng2(i).Month = 1 Or rng2(i).Month = 2 Then
            ary(j) = rng(i).Value
            If j = N - 1 Then Exit For
            ReDim Preserve ary(j + 1)
            j = j + 1
        End If
    End If
Next i

SuperMax_Winter = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(ary)

End Function
```

But I get a `#VALUE!` error.

Comment: you are using `Exit Sub` in a function, so it wont work.

Comment: I've noticed that and have corrected it. But it's not that.

Comment: also, .... `month(rng2(1))`  not `.month`

Comment: Could you explain further how your code doesn't work.  It doesn't return the last `N` non empty cells?  Does `rng2` or `rng` hold a reference to winter months?  How does `rng2(i).Month` work? E.g If I have `15/12/18` in `A1` then `Range("A1").Month` returns a `Object doesn't support this property or method` error.

Comment: It might be worth changing the return to a `Variant` data type so you can return real error values rather than text values saying "Error":  `If RngCnt <> RngCnt2 Then SuperMax_Winter = CVErr(xlValue)`

Comment: I'll do that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Month should be first:

```
If Month(rng2(i).Value)= 11 Or Month(rng2(i).Value)= 12 Or Month(rng2(i).Value)= 1 Or Month(rng2(i).Value)= 2 Then
```

Hope this help.

Comment: you can just use `Month(rng2(i).Value)>=11 or Month(rng2(i).Value)<=2` as well i believe.

Comment: Yes, that's also helpful, but with an `AND`.